# Torque/OpenMPI dynamically allocate nodes based on number of processors

Tags: mpi, pbs, torque, slurm

I was wondering if Torque is smart enough to assign the correct number of nodes based on how many mpi cores you request. For our cluster, we have heterogenous nodes and it can be quite wasteful to just put the number of nodes you want and processors per node. So I was wondering if you could just do something like this

```
qsub -I -l procs:1000
mpiexec -n 1000 mympijob
```

However, torque only allocates one node with this command (as I didn't specify a # of nodes). Is there a way the correct number of nodes based on my number of procs so it can be maximally efficient?

Sidebar - We are probably switching to SLURM soon, is this well within the capabilities?

Comment: What scheduler do you use? Torque can do this but the scheduler has to assign the nodes.

Comment: This works with Torque but you need to also use a scheduler, such as Moab.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, what we do after the resources are allocated is not something that the scheduler can control.

In this case,

```
mpirun/mpiexec -n 1000
```

gets executed after the resources are allocated by the schduler.

The best way to go forward is to use the environment variables set by the scheduler

```
$MPI_HOSTS
```

as the value passed through the switch -n.

example:

```
mpirun $MPI_HOSTS <your program of choice>
```

You can request the number of cores that you want by adding the ppn argument to nodes.

```
qsub -l nodes=2:ppn=16
```

This allocates 32 cores, in two nodes.

Comment: nodes 2:ppn=16 would require that two nodes are freed up each having 16 processors. What if currently you have 3 nodes only with 8 processors each that could be used, but won't, because of that resource management statement?